# Scaling Up a Number

Tags: numbers, rounding, scaling

How do I scale a number up to the nearest ten, hundred, thousand, etc...

Ex.

```
num = 11 round up to 20
num = 15 round up to 20
num = 115 round up to 200
num = 4334 round up to 5000
```

Comment: What language?  Please post the code you have now.  This is not www.do_my_homework_for_me.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this formula might work? Unless you have more examples to show.

```
power = floor(log10(n))
result = (floor(n/(10^power)) + 1) * 10^power
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, if you did 15 it would return for result ((15/10) + 1) * 10 which is 25

Comment: @Rafe Kettler it works if you do integer division or do Math.Floor(15/10)

Comment: yeah, I did mean integer division. It's been updated to be more explicit.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to a decimal (i.e. 11 goes to 1.1, 115 goes to 1.15), then take the ceiling of the number, then multiply it back. Example:

```
public static int roundByScale(int toRound) {
    int scale = (int)Math.pow(10.0, Math.floor(Math.log10(toRound)));
    double dec = toRound / scale;
    int roundDec = (int)Math.ceil(dec);
    return roundDec * scale;
}
```

In this case, if you input 15, it will be divided by 10 to become 1.5, then rounded up to 2, then the method will return 2 * 10 which is 20.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

exp = math.log10(num)
exp = math.floor(exp)
out = math.ceil(num/10**exp)
out = out * 10**exp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int ceilingHighestPlaceValue(int toCeil) 
{
    int placeValue = Math.Pow(10,toCeil.ToString().Length()-1);
    double temp = toCeil / placeValue;
    return= ceil(temp) * placeValue; 
}
```